# How to call method of child component from parent in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I’ve hit an interesting issue that doesn’t fit with Ember’s data down, actions up principle.

I have a code editor component (`code-editor`) sat inside a parent component (`request-editor`). There's a method on the editor component to insert a string at the current cursor position. The parent component includes some buttons to insert things into the editor (e.g. the current date).

I think I'm right in separating the buttons from the editor because the editor is used elsewhere without these buttons.

It obviously doesn't make sense to use a bound variable for this use-case because it's not really data, it's wanting to perform an action. I.e. `{{code-editor insertText=insertText}}` makes no sense.

How is it possible to effectively call `codeEditorChildComponent.insert()` from the parent component? I appreciate it will probably involve coupling them together but they have to be coupled for it to work anyway. The parent component is composed of the child components already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All communications should be done using actions.
I think below is a good way. And you have `code_editor` property in `request-editor` component then could send action to `code-editor` component.

*request-editor.hbs*

```
{{code-editor owner=this}}
```

*request-editor.js*

```
actions:{
  setChild(child){
    this.set('code_editor', child);
  }
}
```

*code-editor.js*

```
didInsertElement(){
  this._super(...arguments);
  this.get('owner').send('setChild', this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tweaked it slightly because I realised I already had an action from the `code-editor` when it's ready but your answer made me realise I could pass `this` with that action then store a handle to it in the parent component for future use.